# Using Glide with RecyclerView and GridLayout. Won't load image on scroll?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm trying to implement a RecyclerView while using Glide to load my images. But for some reason, it will only load the initial few images to populate the screen, but upon scrolling, it won't keep loading new images.

Note that I am using an activity, which contains a fragment, and within that fragment is where I have the RecyclerView.

Here's the code on how I implemented this RecyclerView.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // inflate the view used for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monster_list, container, false);

    // getting reference to the monster list recyclerview.
    mMonsterListRV = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_monster_list);

    // Create the recyclerview for the monster list fragment
    mMonsterListAdapter = new MonsterListAdapter(getContext(), this);
    mMonsterListRV.setAdapter(mMonsterListAdapter);

    mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2,
            GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mMonsterListRV.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);

    return rootView;
}
```

And here's the code for my adapter, up to onBindViewHolder

```
public class MonsterListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MonsterListAdapter.MonsterListViewHolder> {

// create member variable for list of monster icons
private int[] mMonsterIconList;
private Context mContext;
private OnClickHandler mOnClickHandler;

//  create interface for onclick
public interface OnClickHandler {
    void onClick(int monsterSelected);
}

public MonsterListAdapter (Context context, OnClickHandler onClickHandler) {
    mMonsterIconList = DataUtilities.getMonsterIconList();
    mContext = context;
    mOnClickHandler = onClickHandler;
}


@Override
public MonsterListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // inflate the view holder
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_monster_list, parent, false);

    MonsterListViewHolder viewHolder = new MonsterListViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MonsterListViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // Glide implementation
    Glide.with(mContext).load(mMonsterIconList[position]).into(holder.mMonsterIcon);

}
```

Comment: please provide code for MonsterListViewHolder for further assistance.

Comment: I've posted the full adapter class with the viewholder below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the problem. I don't fully understand what caused it, but here's what I did.

After rescaling all my images to (200,200), all the images started loading properly again.

What I think have caused it:
Firstly,I'm very new to android dev, in fact i've not have any programming experience prior to this, so what I'm gonna say below are pure guesses.

When I tried to replace Glide with Picasso, I'll get an out of memory error. And only after resizing my image down to (200,200) did it start working properly. Then I tried the same thing with Glide, making image (200,200), and it started to work as intended.

So my guess is that, my images were too big, which may have caused some kind of memory problem when loading it in the recycler view.